# Can someone explain to me why my Heroku app doesn't use the free dyno hours, but instead just immediately charges me money?

Tags: heroku, dyno

No, I don't have any add-ons that charge me.
I tried reading how the free Dynos work but I didn't find anything regarding this issue. [Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQhGP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert (just deployed my first app), but it seems that there's a clear indication of free or not in the overview tab for your app. For example, I see

[image: dyno formation]

on my app page. Presumably one would turn paid features on and off using the Configure Dynos link.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought I can use my free dyno hours while maintaining my servers awake by setting it to paid dyno. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure thing. Make sure to mark the question as answered if you're satisfied.